# Python jupyter: can't send request to website

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, jupyter-notebook

I'm learning python and trying the below code on Jupyter, but is shown error.

```
import requests
response = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/main_page")

ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='en.wikipedia.org', port=443): Max
retries exceeded with url: /wiki/main_page (Caused by
NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at
0x7f0237dc1e80>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary
failure in name resolution',))`
```

I tried to find answer, but is not sure. Is it because I need to handle the proxy or there is something wrong with my computer operating system? Please help.

Comment: What's your `requests` version? You can run `print requests.__version__`

Comment: hi thx for the reply, it's 2.18.1

Comment: I think my problem might be similar to this https://github.com/requests/requests/issues/3292. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

I got problem sovlved with  using parameter `verify=False`
https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_requests_get.asp

For reference,
I found the answer at here:
https://community.nexthink.com/s/question/0D52p0000ARmsbgCQB/below-code-in-python-tried-on-jupyter-nb-then-it-throws-following-error-sslerror-httpsconnectionpoolhostukfil0083vaukfidintlcom-port1671-max-retries-exceeded-with-url-2queryplatformwindowsplatformmacosqueryselect20i

I'm not sure this is the right solution for your issue. But it worked for me.